# Create a div on click with class, header, paragraph, numbering and delete button via plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this form:

```css
#todos {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<label>Todo Header:</label>
<input type="text" id="header">
  
<br>
  
<label>Todo Paragraph:</label>
<input type="text" id="paragraph">
  
<br>
  
<input type="submit" value="Create Todo!">

<br><br>

<div id="todos"></div>
```

and this divs:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.todo {
  border: 2px solid #EAEAEA;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
  <div class="deleteTodo">x delete todo</div>
  <p class="todoNumber">1</p>
  <h1 class="todoHeader">Test Todo Header</h1>
  <p class="todoDescription">Buy Groceries</p>
</div>

<div class="todo">
  <div class="deleteTodo">x delete todo</div>
  <p class="todoNumber">2</p>
  <h1 class="todoHeader">Test Todo Header</h1>
  <p class="todoDescription">Buy Groceries again</p>
</div>

<div class="todo">
  <div class="deleteTodo">x delete todo</div>
  <p class="todoNumber">3</p>
  <h1 class="todoHeader">Test Todo Header</h1>
  <p class="todoDescription">Buy Groceries again</p>
</div>
```

How could i create such a `.todo` in the `#Todos` div with Javascript that also contains the values of the inputs and a number for each and a delete button?

This is what i have tried so far:

```js
function addTodo() {
  var todoHeader = document.getElementById("header").value;
  var todoParagraph = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
  var todo = document.createElement("div");
  todo.innerHTML = todoHeader + "<br>" + todoParagraph;
  document.getElementById("todos").appendChild(todo);
}
```

```css
#todos {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<label>Todo Header:</label>
<input type="text" id="header">
  
<br>
  
<label>Todo Paragraph:</label>
<input type="text" id="paragraph">
  
<br>
  
<input type="submit" value="Create Todo!" onclick="addTodo();">

<br><br>

<div id="todos"></div>
```

Short summary:

- Div with the class todo should be created
- Div should have a delete button
- A numbering (such as: First todo = 1, second todo = 2 etc.)
- A heading and a description taken from the inputs

I hope it's really not that much work for you but it really means a lot to me. That's why I wanted to thank you in advance!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? There are literally milions of tutorials on JS todo lists online.

Comment: Of course it's possible. And tutorials for to-do lists exist by the millions probably. Posting here means you should show us what you've tried so far, and describe how it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create elements with `document.createElement()`, append them to other elements with `append()` and remove them with `remove()`. For example:

```js
const delete_todo = document.createElement('div');
...
todo.append(delete_todo);
```

To get the todo number you have to count the existing todos. You can do this with `childElementCount`.

After creating the elements you can add `class`, `innerHTML` (or better `textContent`) and the event listener for the delete button. For example:

```js
delete_todo.classList.add('deleteTodo');
delete_todo.textContent = 'x delete todo';
delete_todo.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentElement.remove();
});
```

**Working example**

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#todos');

document.querySelector('#new_todo').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const header_text = document.querySelector('#header').value;
  const todo_text = document.querySelector('#paragraph').value;
  const todo_count = container.childElementCount;

  const todo = document.createElement('div');
  const delete_todo = document.createElement('div');
  const todo_number = document.createElement('p');
  const todo_header = document.createElement('h1');
  const todo_description = document.createElement('p');

  todo.classList.add('todo');
  delete_todo.classList.add('deleteTodo');
  todo_number.classList.add('todoNumber');
  todo_header.classList.add('todoHeader');
  todo_description.classList.add('todoDescription');

  delete_todo.textContent = 'x delete todo';
  todo_number.textContent = todo_count + 1;
  todo_header.textContent = header_text;
  todo_description.textContent = todo_text;

  delete_todo.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
  });

  todo.append(delete_todo);
  todo.append(todo_number);
  todo.append(todo_header);
  todo.append(todo_description);

  container.append(todo);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#todos {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.todo {
  border: 2px solid #EAEAEA;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.deleteTodo {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label>Todo Header:</label>
<input type="text" id="header">

<br>

<label>Todo Paragraph:</label>
<input type="text" id="paragraph">

<br>

<input id="new_todo" type="button" value="Create Todo!">

<br><br>

<div id="todos"></div>
```